# Could not Embed the Full Zapier Experience in web application

Tags: zapier

I am trying to embed the zapier integration within my web application as mentioned in theis documentation - https://platform.zapier.com/embed/full-zapier-experience

But when the page is loaded the Zapier is not embedded and am getting the below exception in browser console.

> Access to fetch at
> 'https://api.zapier.com/elements/zap-templates/?fields=id%2Cwebintent_url%2Ctitle%2Cservices%2Cdescription%2Csteps&limit=25&must_match_all_services=true&service_slugs=&categories='
> from origin 'https://dev-app.mydomain.com' has been blocked by CORS
> policy: Request header field request-context is not allowed by
> Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

I have already added my domain in 'manage domain' section as mentioned here - https://platform.zapier.com/embed/faqs

So what is the issue here?